How can I access the bankName and tags in the pipeline which are dynamically generated
I am using active choices reactive reference parameter plugin of jenkins to dynamically get the banks from another job and get image tags from Nexus, for each bank I create input element for the user to select the tag for each bank.
How can i access which tags were selected and why params object does not have the bankName and tags.
def buildHtml(bankName, tags) {

    def html = new StringBuilder()
    html << "<h5>${bankName}</h5>"
   
    tags.each { tag ->
      html << "<input type='radio' name='${bankName}' value='${tag}'>"
      html << "<label for='${bankName}_${tag}'>${tag}</label><br>"
    }
    html << "<br><br>"
    return html.toString()
}

def bankNames = getStagingBanks()
def htmlResult = new StringBuilder()

bankNames.each { bankName ->
    def tags = getTagsForBank(bankName, encodedCreds)
    def bankHtml = buildHtml(bankName, tags)
    htmlResult << bankHtml
}

// Return the full HTML string for the Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter
return htmlResult.toString()



It renders the parameters correctly but i cant access them in the declarative pipeline.
The advanced usage does refers to this but usage but it doesn't seem to work here.
Trying to print params returns empty value of above parameter.
